# I get an error, when using C-library with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

In Qt Creator I created a small library (in 'Squaring' subfolder of Python project):

*squaring.h:*

```
int squaring(int a);
```

*squaring.c:*

```
#include "squaring.h"
int squaring(int a){
    return a * a;
}
```

In Eclipse, I created Python project that tries to use this library ([according to the instructions from the official website)](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html):

*cSquaring.pxd:*

```
cdef extern from "Squaring/squaring.h":
    int squaring(int a)
```

*Functions.pix:*

```
cimport cSquaring
cpdef int count(int value):
    return cSquaring.squaring(value)
```

*setup.py:*

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules=cythonize([Extension("Functions", ["Functions.pyx"])]))
```

*main.py:*

```
from Functions import count
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = 1
    returned = count(data)
    print(returned)
```

Completed the compilation of C code using (without any errors):

```
python3 setup.py build_ext -i
```

But when I run main.py on execution, I get ImportError:

```
File “/home/denis/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924/pysrc/pydevd.py”, line 2643, in <module>
main()
File “/home/denis/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924/pysrc/pydevd.py”, line 2636, in main
globals = debugger.run(setup, None, None, is_module)
File “/home/denis/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924/pysrc/pydevd.py”, line 1920, in run
return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
File “/home/denis/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924/pysrc/pydevd.py”, line 1927, in _exec
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) # execute the script
File “/home/denis/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_7.3.0.201908161924/pysrc/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py”, line 25, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+“\n”, file, ‘exec’), glob, loc)
File “/home/denis/eclipse-workspace/ConnectionWithCPlusPlus/main.py”, line 1, in <module>
from Functions import count
ImportError: /home/denis/eclipse-workspace/ConnectionWithCPlusPlus/Functions.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: squaring
```

And another project where the code is used Cython (there I did not create A C-library, and wrote the code directly on Cython) works fine.

What is the problem?

Comment: virgesmith, I don't understand you. Please, write what code should I replace and how should I do it.

Answer (score 1):

You included the header files in Cython, but you never actually told it about the *implementation*, i.e. the library where the function is defined. You need to link against the library generated by compiling your C source, as described in the [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#static-linking).

In your `Functions.pyx`, you have to add a comment like this to the top.

```
# distutils: sources = path/to/squaring.c
```